# If I am a collaborator on someone's repository on Github, how do I get their repo onto my terminal?

Tags: git, github, terminal, repository

If I am a collaborator on someone's repository on Github, how do I get their repo onto my terminal? Is it git pull? git fetch? or something else entirely?

Comment: it's `git clone [url to repo]` a simple google search would have been sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `git clone git@....` to get their repo. Just make sure you're not in an existing git repo on your computer when you do it as the `clone` will create a new folder.